# SCSS dynamic media query creation

Tags: sass, media-queries

I'm in the process of writing a small media query framework in SCSS. My goal is to dynamically create media queries from lists. I would like to achieve this by looping through a list and composing them using `@mixin` and `@include` so that you can compose the `@include` based on each of the variables in the list.

```
@mixin pmq($vp){
  @if $vp == small{ 
    @media #{$_s} and ($w: $tw_frty){ 
      @content; 
    }
  }
}
@include pmq(small){
  body{
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

CSS output
    @media screen and (width: 15em){
      body{
        width: 100%;
      }
    }

This outputs a set of media queries based on the list.

```
@each $vp in $viewports{
  @media #{nth($media-types, 8)} and ($vp){
    /**/
  }
}
```

Like so

```
@media screen and (120em) {
  /**/
}
@media screen and (105em) {
  /**/
}
@media screen and (90em) {
  /**/
}
and so on...
```

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to combine the two in such a way that I can create each of the specific `@include` I'm not sure wether I need to create a custom `@function` to achieve this. Any insight would be grateful.

Comment: I don't understand the problem here.  What purpose will a dynamic composed media query serve that makes it different from writing `@media (min-width: $small) { ... }`?

Comment: Yes you can write `@media (min-width: $small){...}`, I'd rather write `@media #{$variable}{...}`. My idea is having code blocks as `@content` in a list that will be looped through and output. Update a list, the loops do the rest. Take a look at what I'm working on. http://bit.ly/14L8Zro

Comment: Please share CSS code that you would like to have as a result, then write a follow-up comment so that we can notice your update.

Comment: First of all, designing for a specific viewport is quite frankly, *doing it wrong* (see: http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/ and http://designshack.net/articles/css/responsive-design-why-youre-doing-it-wrong/).  Second of all, if your mixin is doing the looping *and* using `@content`, you're going to have all of your content applied to each media query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will answer your question(s), however I think I found a trick that may be helpful when resizing devices.

```
    @mixin screen-size{
    
          @media only screen and (max-width:1000px) { @include small-screen-settings; }
          @media only screen and (max-width:800px) { @include medium-screen-settings; }
          @media only screen and (max-width:600px) { @include large-screen-settings; }
    }
    
    @mixin small-screen-settings{
      background:red;
      font-size:120%;
    }
    
    @mixin medium-screen-settings{
      background:green;
      font-size:120%;
    }
    
    @mixin large-screen-settings{
      background:blue;
      font-size:120%;
    }
```

This helped me group all my settings with each screen setting size that I can go to later and change but make that the content of the `@media` query.

Not sure if this is the answer you were looking for but I hope it helps.